# How to separate dataSource and delegate from viewController class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to separate dataSource and delegate from viewController to prevent the viewController from being messy. I read through some posts and found I can separate dataSource like below, create a class to represent `dataSource`:

```
import UIKit

class DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var movies = [String]()

    //MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movies.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell


        cell.textLabel?.text =  movies[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

My question is: What should I do if I want to use properties or call methods of `viewController` class in `DataSource` class? For example, I want to call `presentViewController` when the user select a cell:

```
func tableView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //do something here

    presentViewController(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Why not an extension for each protocol in the same file?

Comment: @vadian How can I store properties If I use extension? like `var movies = [String]()` I don't won't store these properties in viewController Class

Comment: OK, the property for the data source array must be declared in the view controller but this is lesser evil than the dance to pass all required references back and forth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can handle a selected callback:

```
class DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        var movies = [String]()
        private var selectedCallback = ((NSIndexPath)->Void)?

        func selectedItemAtIndex(callback:(NSIndexPath) -> Void) {
            selectedCallback = callback
        }
}
```

callback:

```
func tableView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //do something here

    if let callback = selectedCallback {
       callback(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Using:

```
dataSource.selectedItemAtIndex() {
  [weak self] indexPath in
  // do something ...
  // presentViewController(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hey @anhut Where should I call `dataSource.selectedItemAtIndex()`? In my viewController class?

Comment: @luiyezheng Yes, where you define dataSource/ init instance of DataSource

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to couple your datasource with navigation logic like `presentViewController`. Instead, your datasource can have a delegate, and the datasource will tell the delegate that a certain action was performed by the user. This way, the delegate does not need to know about details like indexPaths; the delegate of the datasource can be the viewController that owns both the collectionView and the dataSource of the collectionView.

UIViewController: has properties UICollectionView and a property YourDataSource. And the viewController sets itself as delegate of YourDataSource instance. In the implementation of YourDataSource's `collectionViewDidSelectItemAtIndexPath`, you can retrieve the movie that lives at that indexPath, and call the delegate with a method like

```
func  dataSource(dataSource: YourDataSource, didSelectMovie movie: YourMovieClass)
```

This will nicely make the viewController unaware of how this movie was selected, and can just a create, setup and present a new viewController for this movie.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching the same thing and used the @Unhtu 's answer. While implementing I came up with the bit easier thing.

**Block As A Parameter**

```
 class DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate 
{     
    private var selectedCallback : ((NSIndexPath)->Void)? // declaring a parameter

    func tableView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

       //Accessing the parameter
        if let callback = selectedCallback {
           callback(indexPath)
        }
    }
```

Assign value to parameter into our `ViewController`

```
var dataSource = DataSource()    
 // Assigning the value to the parameter 
 dataSource. selectedCallback = {
           indexPath in
          // do something ...
           presentViewController(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```